# Play music via android speakers

Tags: android, audio, ipod

I want to make an app that makes it possible to connect an iPod or mp3 player to my Android device and let the Android speakers function as external speakers.

The ideal situation would be to actually read from speaker output so I can connect a stereo mini jack cable.

> Is it possible to read from the headset output with the Android SDK?

[image: The ideal situation would be to read from headset output]

A second option would be to use a mono mini jack instead. I could maybe directly read from microphone and output as a music player. Although, having to use a mono mini jack would be a huge disadvantage, because most people don't own such a cable.

[image: The second option with just a mono mini jack that would read from microphone input.]

*UPDATE*
For my second option I found this link that would let me take a special adapter onto a stereo cable so the iPod output can go into the mic input. It's a TRRS adapter. This works, but still isn't the ideal solution to me. http://www.techlife.net/2012/12/add-an-audio-input-to-android.html

*ANOTHER UPDATE*
I did a test with only a mono cable, but it seems that the mic is not recognized, so I really need the TRRS adapter to make sure that the mic is on. I found some apps that can help me with measuring input volume. I think I can achieve my goal for myself with the adapter, but reading from headset output would be nicer and could actually result in building an app.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand some basic things...

Audio **output** lets you "**take** audio **out** of your device".
It's not audio **input** that would let you "**insert** audio signal **into** your device".

So the concept that you've presented cannot work, because this socket is not able to receive audio signal through normal stereo jack cable (and connector).

You could try to make it work with a device that supports the headphones/mic set (it's a different kind of 3.5 mm jack connector). It's so called TRRS (four-conductor). But to use it in your project you probably would need some cable/socket soldering and maybe even some sort of microporcessor to help processing the signals.

Comment: It is not always true that output is always used for taking it **out** of the device. It is just a simple electrical circuit that can always be inversed as long as software supports it. So making the output a stereo input would be possible if Android supports it.

Comment: I can assure you that NONE of the mass-produced android devices equipped with audio output-only connector will let you reverse the direction of audio signal in it. And the software is not the reason. The thing you say is wrong. It's not "just a simple electrical circuit". Apart from the socket itself there are all the electronics that are different for audio signal going the other direction. Btw my friend: if someone replies with an idea that you like (like my suggestion with TRRS which you used in your update) its nice to upvote or at least say that the update is thanks to my suggestion.